# find match between sheets by loop of multiple range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

hello just started in vba for excel

With two sheets, what is the best way to take
sheet(1).range(a:a)
and find matching values in
sheet(2).range(a:a)
then sum the "total" values in sheets(2).range(b:b) for each match found back
into sheet(1).range(b:b) ?

if there is no matching value highlight red on sheet 1
highlist green when matching on sheet 2

sheet1:

| value | total |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | (1) |
| 3-3 | (20) |
| ss99. | (7) |
| 5 | (highlight red) |

sheet2:

| value | total |
| --- | --- |
| 3-3 | 10 (highlight green) |
| 3-3 | 5 (highlight green) |
| 24 | 1 (highlight green) |
| 3-3 | 5 (highlight green) |
| ss99 | 7 (highlight green) |
| empty | empty |

This is as much code as I written trying to test the iteration between the two sheets.
but I was getting error once it got to the nested loop

```
sub match()

 Dim ws1 as worksheet
 Set ws1 as worksheets(1)
 Dim rg1 as range
 Set rg1 = ws1.range("a:a")
 Dim rg1total as range
 Set rg1total = ws1.range("b:b")

 Dim ws2 as worksheet
 Set ws2 as worksheets(1)
 Dim rg2 as range
 Set rg2 = ws2.range("a:a")
 Dim rg2total as range
 Set rg2total = ws2.range("b:b")

 Dim ws1rowcount as long
 Dim ws2rowcount as long

 ws1rowcount = ws1.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 ws2rowcount = ws2.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim searchvalue as string
 
 Dim rng1 as range
 Dim rng2 as range


 for each rng in rg1
    for each rng2 in rg2
      MsgBox(rng)
      MsgBox(rng2)
     exit for ''' wont iterate to next in rg2
    next ''' wont iterate outer loop rg1
 next

End Sub
```

I found on the microsoft docs an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) using match function

so I was trying implement this code for my use case..

For each value in the first column of the first worksheet, this example searches through the entire workbook for a matching value. If the macro finds a matching value, it sets the original value on the first worksheet to be bold.

```
Sub HighlightMatches()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Declare variables
    Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln As Boolean
       
       'Set up the count as the number of filled rows in the first column of Sheet1.
       iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       
       'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
       For iRow = 1 To iRowL
          'For every cell that is not empty, search through the first column in each worksheet in the
          'workbook for a value that matches that cell value.

          If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1)) Then
             For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
                bln = False
                var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(1), 0)
                
                'If you find a matching value, indicate success by setting bln to true and exit the loop;
                'otherwise, continue searching until you reach the end of the workbook.
                If Not IsError(var) Then
                   bln = True
                   Exit For
                End If
             Next iSheet
          End If
          
          'If you don't find a matching value, don't bold the value in the original list;
          'if you do find a value, bold it.
          If bln = False Then
             Cells(iRow, 1).Font.Bold = False
             Else
             Cells(iRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
          End If
       Next iRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sumifs()` would be a pretty good place to start.

Comment: What is the error you are getting with your loop?

Comment: `MsgBox(rng2)`... `rng2` isn't `set` and has nothing as the value...

Comment: ill look at adding sumifs() to the module, thanks for the mention

Comment: the code that throws an error isnt shown, sorry.. I was testing a few things that are not shown in the code.  I just got stuck when i tried to start iterating between the two sheets. I changed to show another possibility that I tried..

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up Column Data (Dictionary)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumUpColumnData()
        
    ' Define constants.
        
    ' Source (lookup and read)
    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const slCol As String = "A" ' 2. ... here...
    Const svCol As String = "B" ' 3. ... and return the sum of these...
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    ' Destination (lookup and write)
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dlCol As String = "A" ' 1. Lookup this...
    Const dvCol As String = "B" ' 4. ...here.
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
        
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    ' Reference the source lookup and values
    ' column ranges ('slrg', 'svrg').
    
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    
    If srCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in source column range.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Cells(sfRow, slCol).Resize(srCount)
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol)
    
    ' Write the values from the source lookup and values column ranges
    ' to 2D one-based (one-column) arrays ('slData','svData').
    
    Dim slData() As Variant
    Dim svData() As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim slData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): slData(1, 1) = slrg.Value
        ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): svData(1, 1) = svrg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        slData = slrg.Value
        svData = svrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write each unique source lookup value and its corresponding sum
    ' to the 'keys' and 'items' respectively of the source dictionary ('sDict').
    
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    Dim slString As String
    Dim svValue As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        slString = CStr(slData(sr, 1))
        If Len(slString) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            If Not sDict.Exists(slString) Then ' doesn't exist
                sDict(slString) = 0
            'Else ' exists; do nothing
            End If
            svValue = svData(sr, 1)
            If VarType(svValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                sDict(slString) = sDict(slString) + svValue
            'Else ' is not a number; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' is blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Release memory; the source data is in the source dictionary.
    Erase svData
    Erase slData
    
    ' Validate the source dictionary.
    If sDict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No valid data found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('sws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    ' Reference the destination lookup and values
    ' column ranges ('dlrg', 'dvrg').
    
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    
    If drCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in destination column range.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dlCol).Resize(drCount)
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    
    ' Write the values from the destination lookup column range
    ' to a 2D one-based (one-column) array ('dlData').
    
    Dim dlData() As Variant
    
    If drCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim dlData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dlData(1, 1) = dlrg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        dlData = dlrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Define the destination values array ('dvData'),
    ' a 2D one-based (one-column) array.
    Dim dvData() As Variant: ReDim dvData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Using the destination lookup array and the source dictionary,
    ' write the sums to the destination values array.
    
    Dim dlString As String
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        dlString = CStr(dlData(dr, 1))
        If Len(dlString) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            If sDict.Exists(dlString) Then ' found in the source dictionary
                dvData(dr, 1) = sDict(dlString)
            'Else ' not found in the source dictionary; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' is blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next dr
    
    ' Release memory; the destination data is in the destination values array.
    Erase dlData
    Set sDict = Nothing
    
    ' Write the values from the destination values array
    ' to the destination values range.
    dvrg.Value = dvData
    
    ' Inform to not wonder if the code has run or not.
    MsgBox "Added the sums.", vbInformation

End Sub
```